# Text is too far off?

Tags: html, css

It seems it'd work. I don't know why... My description is too far over.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="viewPhoto">
<div id="viewThumb"> 
<img src="$THUMBNAIL_URL$" /><br>
     </div>
<div class="moderPanel" style="float:left">
     $MODER_PANEL$
 </div>
<div id="photo-information" style="float:right"> <strong>Description:</strong></div>
<br />
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

now I understand.

Try to do this:

```
<div id="viewPhoto">
<div id="viewThumb" style="float: left"> 
    <img src="http://images.br.sftcdn.net/br/scrn/73000/73753/santos-5.jpg"  />
</div>
<div id="photo-information" style="float:left; margin-left: 20px"> <strong>Description:</strong></div>
<div class="moderPanel" style="float:left; border:1px solid green; clear: left">
     $MODER_PANEL$
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are putting the div in a float right way.
Try do to left using margin left. Like this:

```
<div id="photo-information" style="float:left; margin-left: 20px"> <strong>Description:</strong></div>
```

Comment: I was wanting it on right side.. That's why I thought float:right; would work.

Comment: then what u actually want zevoxa

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `float:right` CSS statement is causing ithe description to float to the right of your container element. Try using `float:left` together with a small margin like this:

```
<div id="viewPhoto">
    <div id="viewThumb"> 
        <img src="$THUMBNAIL_URL$" /><br>
    </div>
    <div class="moderPanel" style="float:left">
        $MODER_PANEL$
    </div>
    <div id="photo-information" style="float:left; margin-left:15px;"> <strong>Description:</strong></div>
    <br />
    ...
```

Comment: I was wanting it on right side.. That's why I thought float:right; would work.

Comment: I didn't understand. So, why would you like set float right and the same time complain that description is too far off? =)

Comment: http://imgur.com/DtV2InH Like this.

Sorry, I'm new to HTML and CSS I've learned a lot the last past days though. :)

Comment: I answered above! I guess that now is ok. =)